# C# - What is the best way to instantiate a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Recently I have been following some tutorials on Unity, wanting to get into some game programming. Now, I noticed that the guy in the tutorial does the following to copy a parameter to a variable:

```
private Dictionary<string, Inventory> inventoryRequirements;

public Job ( Dictionary<string, Inventory> inventoryRequirements) {
    this.inventoryRequirements = new Dictionary<string, Inventory>(inventoryRequirements);
}
```

and of course this works fine and all but I was just wondering about what the difference is between this and the following:

```
private Dictionary<string, Inventory> inventoryRequirements;

public Job ( Dictionary<string, Inventory> inventoryRequirements) {
    this.inventoryRequirements = inventoryRequirements;
}
```

Comment: When you have a question like this, [consult the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz(v=vs.110).aspx). All types including each constructor is documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first example code snippet, you're cloning the dictionary instance passed in as a parameter using the copy constructor.

Whereas the second approach, you're simply assigning the dictionary reference passed in to the current objects dictionary instance.

The first approach is an effective way to clone a given dictionary's data. This means when the original dictionary is modified, the copy is not affected.

That said, if `Inventory` is a reference type (Which I'd assume it's) then it's important to note that you've cloned the dictionary but if you haven't cloned the `Inventory` values in the dictionary instance, any modifications to the `Inventory` will still be seen through on a given `Job` instance dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you intialize an instance of a dictionary that contains elements copied from the dictionary you pass to the constructor and you make use of the default equality comparer for the key type. For further info please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz(v=vs.110).aspx). Then you assign a reference to the newly created dictionary to the `inventoryRequirements` field.

Whereas in the second case you just assign a copy of the reference to the original dictionary to the `inventoryRequirements` field.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to really understand what exactly is going on, let's have a look at a quick code snippet.

- [Your first snippet](https://repl.it/repls/FeistyModernRadius)
- [Your second snippet](https://repl.it/repls/LateSlightTransformations)

Observing the outputs you can see that in the second case, your original dictionary was actually modified, and the value mapped to the key "test" was re-assigned to 0.

As you may have figured out, when you use `new Dictionary<string, Inventory>(inventoryRequirements);` you actually create a *clone* of your original dictionary, so the instantiated class can modify its copy all it wants without affecting your copy.

Whereas, when you directly pass the *same* dictionary, any modifications made by the instantiated class will be visible in your class, and you lose control over your dictionary as you've essentially given the instantiated class complete control over it.

Now, as a general rule of OOP, you should keep your fields (that aren't required by other classes/objects) to yourself. By that logic, you should pass your object (not a copy) if:

1. You will not need the object again or
2. Your object is very large and can't be cloned reasonably **Keep in mind that the GC will automatically delete your object if it goes out of scope immediately** or
3. The object is a primitive (you'll get a deep copy, so it will already be a clone.)

Now, if you don't need any of the above you should probably be passing a copy.